# Can I substitute things other than arguments in a JDBC prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create tables programatically and getting this error:

```
Failure to execute query with SQL:
create table if not exists ? like other_table_name  ::  [new_table_name]
BatchUpdateException:
 Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''new_table_name' like other_table_name' at line 1
 SQLState: 42000
 Error Code: 1064
```

I'd also like to be able to do things like:

```
select * from ? where thing = ?;
```

I would post the code because it's Clojure and I think this is a JDBC (rather than a library) issue.

Should I expect a prepared statement like this to work?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. A prepared statement is a statement that the database can prepare, i.e. decide how it will execute it, which table it affects, which index it uses, etc. To know that, it needs to know the table used in the statement.